# angularJS notification when element is removed

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a new directive and I wondering how to be notified when angular remove the element from the DOM.
My aim is to add a jquery animation when an element is removed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are trying to animate the removal of element you need to do this before it is removed.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShadowBelmolve/sg4tK/2/) demonstrating this.

In the first section you listen the `$destroy` event that angular call to elements that are being removed from DOM.

In the second case I've created a directive that fadeOut and remove the element automatic.

In the third case the directive just fadeOut the element and the removal is passed to controller.

If you want to fadeOut the element that are removed then you can't use the first option.

Between the second and the third I personally suggest the third because it is more flexible.

Comment: whasts the problem with IE8? If the app don't even render the repeaters is probably because I haven't added "class='ng-app'" on the example

Comment: The problem about the answer is that relies on binding to the element's click for remove function. I think for the directive to work without interfering with controller/ui logic, the fadeOut should be triggered directly when the element is actually removed from the list variable. I tried to put the fade code inside the $destroy event, however because angular remove the element immediately after the splice action in the array list, the fade animation has no time to proceed. Any improvement from your solution above?

Comment: "If you want to fadeOut the element that are removed then you can't use the first option.". For fadeOut use option 2 or 3.

Comment: There's one small mistake in that jsFiddle, see updated one here: http://jsfiddle.net/sg4tK/69/ 
On line 13 `$(element).parent().fadeOut(1000, function() {` `element ` doesn't need to be wrapped in the selector as you're already including the jQuery library but you need to make sure it's loaded before Angular so Angular can pick it up.