# How to use directive to trigger jquery animation on both add and remove item in a list inside angularjs?

Tags: jquery, animation, angularjs, directive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [angularJS notification when element is removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548390/angularjs-notification-when-element-is-removed)

As title, basically I want to do a fadeIn/fadeOut when the list has new item added/old item removed. Now I have to do the animation for add via a directive but the remove animation via the controller, how can I consolidate together and just use directive as its not really related to the core logic?